# Cycle2 - trigger slide change when the user scrolls using mouse

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-cycle2

As the title suggests I have a horizontal slideshow and I'd like it so when the user scroll their mousewheel the slide will change - is there something built into cycle2 that can already do this? I've had a look at the demos/docs and couldn't see anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured it out - for those interested:

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').on( 'DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function ( event ) {
        if( event.originalEvent.detail > 0 || event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 ) { //alternative options for wheelData: wheelDeltaX & wheelDeltaY
            $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('next');
            console.log('Down');
        } else {
           $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('prev');
           console.log('Up');
        }
        //prevent page fom scrolling
        return false;
});
```